# AJAX call not displaying any data when number of rows are huge

Tags: javascript, ajax

The following code is displaying data when the number of rows returned is less than 40. But if more than 40 rows are returned, there is no data displayed on the front end.

My code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/getdata.htm', 
    dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
    success: function(data) {},
    error:function(){
        alert("Something went wrong");
    }
});
```

After 40 rows `data.length` is showing as 0, while data is not equal to null.
The error function is never executed, what is the problem?

Comment: The title of a question should describe the question, and therefore should not contain phrases like "Any one ever got a situation like this!!!!!!!".

Comment: Try `alert(typeof data === "string" ? "not parsed" : "json");`

Comment: Go into your developer tools (F12 usually) and find the ajax request in there. Examine the response body. If it contains data, but data in your ajax request is empty, something must have gone while parsing the data. If the response body is empty, check your error logs on the server.

Comment: @Sumurai8: Yes response body has data, but ajax request is not displaying data. How to check error logs on the server??

Comment: Copy the entire body and put it in jsonlint as suggested below. I suppose the body is prematurely cut off. The error log on the server will probably say that the maximum size is exceeded.

Comment: @user2679632 Are you seeing any errors in the console? It's possible that the server returns a malformed JSON after 40 rows for some reason, and this causes an error while jQuery tries to parse it. In this case, neither of the callbacks will be executed.

Comment: @godfrzero No, there no errors displayed in the console.

Comment: @Sumurai8: checked in fire bug....the returned json response contain all the data. No problem in json being returned.

Comment: @Sumurai8 you have any idea, how to resolve this?

Comment: How sure are you that the success function isn't executed? Have you tried putting a console.log in both the error and success function? Are you aware that ajax is asynchronous and any handling of data should be designed around that. Have you pulled the json through jsonlint?

Comment: @Sumurai8 Hey....yes i have retrieved my json using firebug. Then put my Json response in to jsonlint, it is showing valid JSON. And yes success box is executed. I have confirmed by putting response in alert. Getting all the data inside the alert using alert("WITH RESULTS"+result);, but after giving another alert which is like alert($(result.viewUserData)[0]); giving value undefined.

Comment: @jantimon returning json as alert.

Comment: @user2679632 what version of jquery are you using? Also are there any unusual characters such as accents on peoples names, that could be tripping up jquery? Are you able to provide a snippet (or all) of the json or is it to sensitive to make public?

Comment: @AlexKey@jantimon@Sumurai8 : I dont know, how it came to my mind. I was going through eval function from javascript on web. Then i parse my json response variable usinf eval and it worked.
The reason being something wrong with parsing. till 40 records if we see the response, it displays as object and after that if you put alert and see value of response, it shows all the values of the JSOn not just a object. So i parsed it, and its working for any no. of records now.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Hi @user2679632 glad you've got it sorted.  But you shouldn't need to use an eval function. As of jQuery 1.4 it will convert a JSON string into a javascript object for you. So the "data" variable will be a javascript object

Comment: @AlexKey I am using 1.8 version, still I was getting the issue. Not able to find any other reason or cause of this, because everything is correct at place whether its JSON response or format. Its just not getting parsed properly. 
Yes you are right, data variable is a javascript object but only till no. of records are less than 40.

Comment: @user2679632 maybe try the uncompressed development version of jQuery and try to step into the parse functions. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e53a91909061c7a7280a274990db179b94db81b6/speed/jquery-basis.js#L496

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done already a good place to start is:

Using a tool like http://fiddler2.com/ or http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel you can check to see json is being returned.

And then pop your JSON into a tool like http://jsonlint.com/ to validate the json is in the correct format.

Comment: Hey.. i have retrieve json response from firebug, its giving proper response. Then i checked in jsonlint, it also says valid json. Then what is the problem??